# not getting exact result in closed itemsets

Tags: java, arraylist, data-mining

in the variable total(instance of array list class) I have the list of frequent item sets. while I finding closed frequent item sets it displaying wrong result.

in intersection method i am going to find whether the two array lists are same or not.

```
     ArrayList close=new ArrayList();

                System.out.println("total: "+total);

            for(int i1=0;i1<total.size();i1++)
            {
                List list1=(List)total.get(i1);

                if(close.size()==0)
                close.add(list1);
                else
                {
                    List tp=intersection(list1,close);

                if(tp.size()!=0)
                close.add(list1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("close: "+close);

    for(int i2=0;i2<total.size();i2++)
        {
            List list1=(List)total.get(i2);

            if(close.size()!=0)
            {
                for(int i1=0;i1<close.size();i1++)
                {
                List list2=(List)close.get(i1);
                List tp=intersect(list1,list2);

                if(tp.size()!=0)
                {
                    if(!close.contains(list1))
                    {
//here hm is containing all the list of frequent item sets with their support count.

                        if(((Integer)hm.get(list1)>(Integer)hm.get(list2))&&((Integer)hm.get(list1)!=(Integer)hm.get(list2)))
                        {
                            close.add(list1);
                            //System.out.println(list1+": "+hm.get(list1)+"  "+list2+": "+hm.get(list2));
                        }

}
                        }
                        }
                     }
                 }


public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) 
    {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T t : list1) 
        {
            List<T> list3=(List<T>)list2.get(0);
            if(!list3.contains(t)) 
            {
                return list1;
            }
            if(list.size()!=0)
            return list1;
        }
        return list;
    }

in total object values are like this

total: [[1, 3, 7, 9, 12], [1, 3, 7, 9], [1, 3, 9, 12], [1, 7, 9, 12], [1, 3, 7,
12], [3, 7, 9, 12], [3, 9, 12], [3, 7, 9], [3, 7, 12], [1, 7, 12], [1, 9, 12], [
7, 9, 12], [1, 7, 9], [1, 3, 12], [1, 3, 9], [1, 3, 7], [1, 9], [1, 12], [1, 3],
 [12, 15], [1, 7], [3, 12], [7, 9], [9, 12], [7, 12], [3, 15], [3, 9], [3, 7], [
3], [1], [7], [12], [9], [15]]

in close close: [[1, 3, 7, 9, 12], [1, 3, 9, 12], [3, 9, 12], [1, 9, 12], [1, 3, 12], [1,
 3, 9], [12, 15], [3, 15], [1, 9], [1, 12], [1, 3], [3, 12], [9, 12], [7, 12], [
3, 9], [15], [3], [1], [7], [12], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your  `intersection` code is just badly badly broken.

Use **unit tests**.

Try your code on computing the intersection of `[1,2,3]`, `[3,4,5]`.

If I'm not mistaken, it always returns the first list.